# I dropped a nickel in my drink

Tags: riddle

I dropped a nickel in my drink

And stirred it around

This made me think

Of a little bird's sound

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could you be thinking of

> [Covfefe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391945/what-does-covfefe-exactly-mean)

I dropped a nickel  in my drink, And stirred it around

> A nickel is five (*V* in Roman numerals) and *Coffee* is your drink and anagram this for *covfefe*.

This made me think, Of a little bird's sound

> Covfefe was a recent tweet (bird sound) which went viral.